# .NET CF 3.5 mobile app building slowly in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have been working with a Windows Mobile 6 app that is built with .NET Compact Framework 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008. The application builds incredibly slow, spending a majority of the time doing the PlatformVerificationTask.

How do I speed up the build?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to stop the PlatformVerificationTask in a distributed development environment I would suggest adding the following to the mobile app's project file:

```
<Target Name="PlatformVerificationTask">
</Target>
```

This will overwrite the PlatformVerificationTask in \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.CompactFramework.Common.targets

Comment: Thanks. It works. Just add this before the end of the *.csproj file (or *.vbproj in case of VB projects). This is much easier than the Condition="'$(SkipPlatformVerification)' != 'true'" that is suggested here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46bcb905-1fa6-4f1b-a8ae-b3ddb86bd9c6/how-to-reduce-build-time-of-c-net-cf-windows-form-based-project?forum=netfxcompact. Alas this solution worked for me while the one where the .targets file was modified did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what IceSlurpy said about 10 hours ago.

For me to understand it, I simply "uncheck" the Build and Deploy projects that are not necessary.

If a Setup.CAB is part of your project, unchecking the Setup project can save a LOT of time!

[image: Configuration Manager]