# Deployment Speed

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, genexus

I´m using Genexus X Ev 2 to build .Net Mobile (Win Mob 5) Applications. 
The device (Motorola Symbol MC3090) is connected trough cradle to my PC USB Port (Windows Mobile Device Center / DMA).

All works.

The only problem is that when i want to run the app, Genexus DE takes a very long time to copy the CAB file to the device. The CAB has 1.7Mb and it takes about 2 minutes.

If I copy manually through Windows Explorer, It´s fast. About 20 seconds.

Does anyone know if there is something specific to Genexus to speed up this deployment?

Comment: Do you have some version of Visual Studio Installed? which one ?

Comment: I Do. Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

GeneXus uses APIs of Visual Studio to deploy the cabs. So the experience should be similar to the one of using directly Visual Studio 2008 in this case. (If no Visual Studio 2003,2005 or 2008 instance is found, [RAPI](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Pocket+pc+network+programming/Chapter+9.+Desktop+Synchronization/Remote+API+RAPI/)is used).

A thread related to this, regarding Visual Studio, is this one: [.NET CF 3.5 mobile app building slowly in VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779850/net-cf-3-5-mobile-app-building-slowly-in-vs-2008)
Seems that to accelerate the deployment, you can let empty the PlatformVerificationTask:

In the file \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.CompactFramework.Common.targets

Another tip is setting this property in GeneXus "Deploy required SDKs" to "No".
If it is set to  Yes (default) in each F5 (Build/Run) GeneXus installs the required SDKs which in the output will be shown as

```
Installing .NET Compact Framework ....

Installing SQL Server Mobile....

Installing SQL Server Client....
```